# When /rooms/timeout/... returns an error, it isn't clearly visible

Tags: feature-request, chat, error-message, chat-timeout

When the room timeout feature returns an error (for example due to rate limiting, "You can perform this action again in 3 seconds"), you don't get a message that tells that there's an error. For other rate-limited actions (e.g. starring), it shows up the actual error in a notification bar at the top of the chat room. This bar is absent here, but it would be useful here. You'd have to look in your browser console to see the actual error, in the response.

Can timeout errors please be displayed more clearly?

Comment: More likely a bug :P

Comment: @berserk this feature was lifted from the mod-tools and I don't think they come with extensive error handling. Code that isn't there can't have bugs. So it must be a new feature